# Automatic Compare Layout of 2 Structs in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

2 `struct`s came from different header files from different libraries. The libraries have a lot of similar stuff.

How can I ensure that the memory layout of them are binary compatible? In addition how can I check the naming of them are equal? The checking should be done at compile time.

As an example:

```
//Header of Library A
namespace LibA {
  struct Item {
    uint32_t A;
    uint8_t B;
    uint8_t pad1,pad2,pad3;
  };
  void FunctionOfLibA(Item *a);

}


//Header of Library B
namespace LibB {
  struct Item {
    uint32_t A;
    uint8_t B;
    uint8_t pad1,pad2,pad3;
  };
  void FunctionOfLibB(Item *a);
}

//My Usage
LibA::Item item;
LibA::FunctionOfLibA(&item);
LibB::FunctionOfLibB((LibB::Item*)(void*)(&item)); //I want to check if this cast is safe.
//So I have to ensure the alignment, pack, order etc. are the same for both LibB::Item and LibA::Item
```

Ok - in the above example it's easy to do it the manual way with `sizeof(...)` and `offsetof(...)`. As an alternative I Can manually check the header files for each new library version.

But the question is to do it in an automatic way like `static_assert(issame(LibA::Item,LibB::Item),"Check")`?

Comment: I think we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Please explain what you need this for. I suspect a risky hack.

Comment: `static_assert(issame(LibA::Item,LibB::Item),"Check")` But they're not the "same". Indeed, the only thing you could do with such a check is *maybe* `std::bit_cast` between them, if they're trivially copyable. But that's a C++20 feature, so you can't even do that in C++14.

Comment: I think one could do something at least at runtime using [`boost::pfr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_pfr.html): Get the structs as tuples, compile time check that the sizes are the same and runtime check that the addresses of the elements are the same. Checking for identical names, however, is not possible.

Comment: Can you do `namespace LibB { using LibA::Item;}` or the other way instead of the second definition?

Comment: I agree with Yunnosch, it seems a XY problem. And in either case it doesn't work, even if they have the same layout they can be not compatible for a `memcpy` or a casting. For example, what will happen if you have two structure with same members, but with `#pragma pack` used only in one?

Comment: What if you write client code like this `LibB::FunctionOfLibB((LibB::Item*)(void*)(&item));` and either library changes the layout of its `Item` at some point? Wouldn't this force you to re-write all of your code?

Comment: @paolo That's correct. As long as the structs are the same, i can use this simple cast. Otherwise I have to write some conversion routines. And thats it the reason, why I want to check the "compatibility" of these structs at compile time. If they aren't anymore equal, the code compilation should stop with an error.

Comment: I'd go with the converting routines from the beginning as (I believe; I may be wrong) that reinterpret cast is undefined behavior even if `LibB::Item` and `LibA::Item` have the same layout.

Answer (score 2):

In C++20 there are the [layout-compatibility and pointer-interconvertibility traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) so you can do it with [`std::is_layout_compatible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_layout_compatible)

```
static_assert(std::is_layout_compatible_v<LibA::Item, LibB::Item>, "Check")
```

[Demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmAJykAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0bEJCnUNTdmtQ109xaUDAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMwcjeWADUJutuBACeiZgA%2BgTETIQKB9gmGgCCG1s7mPuHTiyGeIn3jxeZk2DG2Xj2BzcTiGxEwrABz0BzDYCkSTBWuyCESe%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%2BBdSSPdUUx9DE91tAdHTDI0p3ZG9dj/QInQNF9t0/fKEwjMDr2SfD3TXdMd1mPMCjESsehXJgqw8ChaEYS5smqHyXHzVxki7MAyDILsEBXCaNELhA%2BFWJY/64IQJD7MCrS7B4On0MGZGzLwylaPMEBIIZxn6RACtiyA2rIIkiSflwcTnOsXDnKoNO2bQ9mOc5wVucw0ZebwPmMAQ/mBS5oWGMAEXYVF/2xXN2EJUlKWrNh6WocFWWRh5eVB1LxBFbb8xlUwlXVXVDW251wiiOIHXNfIShqC5ujyoNxgjdz4cTfOOEzekc3eleq1cxYG27N6O17e0zgQK4L3%2BMd0MzLKH3pL3Q95OkA93X9vYQ4Do/T9UkOo0U316Cj88o5PP1Yzj7UUbChOqaH6FSWTnBG7TLAKOrOo6wx%2BtM5zo27LzRDi4L/4i0ZYsC6yksUVRWY8wECBn6FXOiXF1gMS4OsLiEl1jMTYriHifIhIcBEqQMSkFJLSV4LJeSeNAFqU0nLEAG5EgpSViraIoRWCrAplTGmdMGZMxZgwNmvBMD4DfvqPQudWrZ2kLnbqBc%2Bp6BqtcRI8c0En1wThTgZoUoUMlKGXYDDqa03pozZmxBWbsy/sZX%2BXB/7S2oqQEBiowHE3QaJEA2DT7BXwbYRSACVJANIHRXEXAGIsTiJIOBZhJDrGQRoPkqDQ7rFJo4zgUtAHWN2g4mSMTXEy3mLFBy6RzpAA%3D%3D%3D)

Note that it may not work if the structs aren't standard-layout, or using non-compatible types, for example if one uses `signed char`/`unsigned char` and the other uses `char` (when `char` is signed/unsigned on that platform respectively) then they're incompatible

If your C++ version is older than that, sorry you'll have to upgrade or find another way, like modifying the 2 libraries or manually using `sizeof` and `offsetof`. However if you don't need portability then on some compilers you can try to use their intrinsics, for example `__is_layout_compatible` on GCC 12+